# Is there an installation package builder for Drupal?

Tags: 7, distributions, installation

Does anybody know of any websites that provide a service that allows you to select which modules you want, and download a pre-assembled installation package with the selected modules already in the /modules/ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your own easily with the [Drush Make](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) module; the [Profiler Builder](http://drupal.org/project/profiler_builder) module will tell you what to include in your make file.

This requires you have some knowledge of using drush.

Comment: See also: http://drupal.org/node/1368242, which contains a drush command to generate profiles (still under development)

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. That's what I thought. I wonder if there is a call for a website that provides a kind of package building service, such as on the jQuery UI site?

Comment: This kind of site already exists : http://drushmake.me/